# Implement Gaussian sum function in OCaml with lambda expression

Tags: function, lambda, sum, ocaml, gaussian

I have to write a function `sum` that takes as first argument a value `n`. The second argument is a function `f` so that sum calculates the Gaussian sum.

In a second step, I have to implement the`sum_gauss (int->int)` using `sum` and a lambda expression.

This is my idea for the function `sum`:

```
let rec sum (n:int) (f:int->int) : int = 
  if n < 1 then 0 
  else sum (n-1) f + f n
```

And this is `sum_gauss` which throws an error:

```
let sum_gauss = sum ((i:int) -> fun (i:int) : int -> i)
```

The error is:

```
Line 1, characters 30-32:
Error: Syntax error: ')' expected
Line 1, characters 22-23:
  This '(' might be unmatched
```

I don't understand why this error is raised because every left bracket is matched by a right bracket.

Comment: Your code contains a syntax error, due to the unwanted `->`. The message is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am supposed to work with lambda expressions. That is why I wrote arrows.

Comment: There are multiple ways to introduce lambdas in OCaml, but the most straightforward one is the one you already use, with `fun arg -> code`. Also, note that OCaml has typing inference, so you don't need to explicitly type all your variables.

Comment: How would I correctly write the lambda expression then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting with type inference cleaning things up:

```
let rec sum n f = 
  if n < 1 then 0 
  else sum (n-1) f + f n
```

If you wish to add all number from 1 to `n`. you need to pass the number and the function to `sum_gauss` as separate arguments.

```
let sum_gauss n = sum n (fun x -> x)
```

Of course, `fun x -> x` is really just `Fun.id`.

```
let sum_gauss n = sum n Fun.id
```

If you feel like being extra clever and you're already using the `Fun` module you can use `Fun.flip` to pass `Fun.id` as the second argument of `sum` and elide `n` from the definition entirely. The fact that `sum` is not polymorphic avoids weak typing issues with partial application.

```
let gauss_sum = Fun.(flip sum id)
```